# What is the limit of $2c^{n-1}-c^{n-2}-...-c-1$ when $n\to\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have a sequence in which the value of the $n^{th}$, $x_n$ is given by

$$x_n=2c^{n-1}-c^{n-2}-...-c-1$$

Where $c>0,$
then in the limit when $n\to\infty$ what is $x_n$?

Comment: What if $c\ge 1$?

Comment: This looks awfully similar to your previous question. You haven't had time to try this properly since I told you the closed form for $x_n$.

Comment: You get a recursive formula: $x_{n+1}=cx_n-1$.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I just have no clue how to do this.

Comment: Another way to look at it is $x_{n+1}=c^{n-1}(2c-3)+x_{n}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First simplify the expression. When $c \ne 1$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
2c^{n-1} - c^{n-2} - \cdots - c - 1
&= 2c^{n-1} - \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} c^i \\
&= 2c^{n-1} - \dfrac{c^{n-1} - 1}{c-1} \\
&= \frac{2c^n-3c^{n-1}+1}{c-1}
\end{align*}$$
Now consider what happens if $0<c<1$ and if $c>1$ separately.

When $c = 1$, the expression is equal to $2-(n-1) = 3-n$, so tends to $-\infty$.

Comment: Should be $+1$ instead of $-1$.

Comment: @velutluna: Fixed, thanks! It took me a moment to work out which of the many "$-1$"s you were referring to ;)

Comment: Amusing that there is a limit when $c=\frac{3}{2}$ but no other $c>1$.

Comment: Does $x_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ when $c>1$ and c is not $3/2$?

Comment: Not necessarily. Notice that $2c^n-3c^{n-1} = c^{n-1}(2c-3)$, so this term will tend to either $\infty$ or $-\infty$ depending on whether $2c-3$ is positive or negative.

Answer (score 0):

$x_n=2c^{n-1}-c^{n-2}-\ldots-c-1=2c^{n-1}-(c^{n-2}+c^{n-3}+\ldots+1)=$
$$=2c^{n-1}+\frac{1-c^{n-1}}{1-c}=\frac{2c^n-3c^{n-1}+1}{c-1}$$

When $n\to \infty$ and $c>1$ the prevalent term is the maximum degree, that is $n-1$ thus the limit is $+\infty$

if $0<c<1$ then

$$x_n\to\frac{1}{1-c} \text{ as }n\to\infty$$
because $c^{n-1}\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$ and $0<c<1$

If $c=1$ then $x_n=2-1-1-1\ldots-1\to-\infty$ as $n\to\infty$

Hope this helps

Comment: Nope, the sequence is constant when $c=\frac{3}{2}$, so your first statement is false (but almost true.) In general, for a fixed polynomial, the term of largest degree dominates, but in this case, you have different polynomials for each $n$, and there are more terms subtracted.

Answer (score 0):

If you note that:

$$x_1=2\\x_{n+1}=c^{n-1}(2c-3)+x_{n}.$$ then $$x_{n}=(2c-3)(c^{n-2}+c^{n-3}+\cdots + c+1)+2$$

Now, this sequence converges when $|c|<1$, and when $2c-3=0$.